# SocketException between our Load Balancers and Tomcat during Garbage Collection

Tags: linux, garbage-collection, java-6, tomcat7

We have noticed the following problem: whenever our Tomcat JVM performs full GC, the requests to create a connection between the LB ant the Tomcat are failed. This is very problematic since all these requests will never get the chance to arrive to the application server.

This problem occured even when we have pointed one Tomcat to the other without any LB in between.

Are there any definition that can be done in the JVM / Tomcat / Linux that will make the HTTP connection to wait the time till the GC  ends and the application JVM will receive the request.

We are using Java6, Tomcat7, and Linux Ubuntu OS.

Thanks,
Yosi

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the concurrent garbage collector using the 'XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC' option? This essentially performs garbage collection in the background so that there aren't nearly as many (if any) "stop the world" full GCs.

Comment: I have tried these option, the button line is that full GC might happen at some point, and I do not want to lose clients that tries to connect during this pause, this is why I am looking for something at the definitions of the TCP level

Comment: Although you can never guarantee that a Full GC won't happen, you can prevent them in practice. First, make sure that the heap for tomcat is adequately sized. Second, you can use the following option to trigger the point at which a background collection will be initiated: -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=<value>. A value of, say, 75 would initiate a background collection when the heap reached 75% capacity.

Comment: You'll need to adjust those two settings to ensure that XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction is low enough that the background collector has time to run before the heap is entirely exhausted (otherwise a full GC results). XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction also needs to be high enough that the background collector isn't being perpetually triggered when the system is unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable concurrent garbage collection as described in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Also try other GC configs.